# What are some free C# PDF Reader Libraries that handle iref streams?

Tags: gratis, library, pdf, c#

I am trying to programmatically read a pdf file that I was given.  I am not so familiar with C# so I tried PdfSharp to see if I could read my pdf.  With the latest version (1.32) I get:

```
Cannot handle iref streams.  The current implementation of PDFsharp cannot handle this PDF feature introduced with Acrobat 6.
```

Since PDFSharp cannot handle this feature, can someone give me a recommendation of such C# pdf libraries that can handle iref streams?

Comment: It seems that the latest beta package of PdfSharp (1.50.4000-beta3b) can handle iref streams